# I am unable read register values in ADS1282

Tags: adc, spi

I am interfacing ADS1282 with LPC1768 through SPI. Currently I am not onnected analog supplies. Only digital supplies connected.I am trying to check whether communication is happening or not.But I can't read the register values.

These are the steps I followed.

1.sent 0x11 for - Stop continuous reading.

2.sent 0x20 for - Reading 1st register.

3.sent 0x00 for reading only on e register.

4.Dummy write 0x00 for reading data.

Given delay 100 microseconds in between instructions.
I am getting only 0x00.
I checked different registers.
SCLK = 3 MHZ

Comment: Can you talk to the chip at all?

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Comment: The wrong clock polarity might be a reason. Can you monitor communication with an oscilloscope/logic analyzer? It's likely to be more a configuration issue than a hardware problem. You could provide us with some code, but I guess it's the wrong board in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet says the chip is internally held in reset until power supplies are valid. Do not partially power chips unless datasheet specifically allows this under some conditions.